# Get coordinates of a grid

Tags: javascript, math

I have an endless grid and need a javascript function to get coordinates within the area of a start and endpoint. The grid looks like this.

```
 _______________________
|       |       |       |
| -1,-1 |  0,-1 |  1,-1 |
|_______|_______|_______|
|       |       |       |
| -1,0  |  0,0  |  1,0  |
|_______|_______|_______|
|       |       |       |
| -1,1  |  0,1  |  1,1  |
|_______|_______|_______|
```

So lets say I want all coordinates from (-1,-1) to (0,0). In this case I would get the 4 values (-1,-1), (0,-1), (-1,0), (0,0).

I know this are basic mathematics but I don't find a clever solution here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
function GetCoordinatesBetween(xStart, xEnd, yStart, yEnd) {
    var curX = xStart;
    var curY = yStart;
    var res = []; // Array for result coordinates    

    while (curX <= xEnd) {
        while (curY <= yEnd) {
            res.push({ x: curX, y: curY });
            curY++;
        }
        curX++;
        curY = yStart;
    }

    return res;
}
```

This function returns your coordinates as array in the following format:

```
[
    0: { x: -1, y: -1},
    1: { x: -1, y: 0},
    ...
]
```